# Hi, How to parse xml with descendants within descendants C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, linq-to-xml, descendant

I am trying to parse this xml and can successfully get the name and description but putting together the image is tricky. Both separate code parses work but I'd like to do one parse so I can bind them all to one listbox.

The xml looks like this

```
<stickers>
    <sticker>
        <imageData>
            <baseImageUrl> ... want this  </baseImageUrl>
            <sizes>
                <size>  don't care about this </size>
            </size>
            <imageUrlSuffix> ..want this </imageUrlSuffix>
        </imageData>
        <description>.... want this </description>
        <name>  --want this </name>
    <sticker>
<stickers>
```

My code works for both but separately. How do I combine this into one parse...

```
XDocument streamFeed = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(response.Content));
var imagedata = from query in streamFeed.Descendants("sticker").Elements("imageData")
    select new Stickers
    {
        image = (string)query.Element("baseImageUrl") + "huge" + (string)query.Element("imageUrlSuffix"),
    };


var data = from query in streamFeed.Descendants("sticker")
    select new Stickers
    {
        name = (string)query.Element("name"),
        description = (string)query.Element("description"),   
    };

stickersListBox.ItemsSource = imagedata.Union(data);
```

The data displays in the listbox but with the stickers above the description and not side by side.

Thanks

---

Thanks to Thomas below, the following code works but some user profiles get a Null Referenced Exception (including my own profile which obviously has data) Thanks Thoamas for the assistance perhaps this is an unrelated bug?

```
XDocument streamFeed = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(response.Content));

                    var query =
                        from sticker in streamFeed.Root.Descendants("sticker")
                        let imageData = sticker.Element("imageData")
                        select new Stickers
                        {
                            name = (string)sticker.Element("name"),
                            description = (string)sticker.Element("description"),
                            image = (string)imageData.Element("baseImageUrl") + "huge" + (string)imageData.Element("imageUrlSuffix")
                        };

                    stickersListBox.ItemsSource = query;
```

Comment: It sounds like the Xml is being parsed just fine.  You are saying that all the data is displayed, but not the way you want it to be displayed?

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk Yes it parses correctly but does not display correctly since the data is added to the list after the images as separate objects rather than an object with (image+name+description)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this should do what you want:

```
XDocument streamFeed = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(response.Content));
var query =
    from sticker in streamFeed.Root.Elements("sticker")
    let imageData = sticker.Element("imageData")
    select new Stickers
    {
        name = (string)sticker.Element("name"),
        description = (string)sticker.Element("description"),   
        image = (string)imageData.Element("baseImageUrl") + "huge" + (string)imageData.Element("imageUrlSuffix")
    };

stickersListBox.ItemsSource = query;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! The code gives no errors but the data doesn't display (probably empty). I did a small change to your code streamFeed.Descendants("sticker") instead of root and it returns the data for name and description but null referenced exception for image.

Comment: Did you post the full XML in the question? I used Elements instead of Descendants because it's more efficient, but it requires that you know the exact structure of the document

Comment: I edited my original post the code that works but some errors probably unrelated.... Thanks